# Write same vertex labels with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, trees

I am writing an article on graph coloring and trying to make this type of labeled tree in TikZ. (See the attached Figure)

The problem is that I have to use same color label (English letter) for many vertices. Then, labeling many vertices with same English letter, how can I recognize the vertices, position these vertices and draw edges between them ?

[image: A sample coloring of a tree]

I want to draw this type of images. Please give suggestions.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) We're always happy to help you, but you've got to show us what you've tried - we will not do your work for you. Basic drawing commands for TikZ can be found in many places on the internet with a quick search. If you're completely new to it, I would suggest starting [here](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf).

Comment: It kind of seems to me that you're confusing the text of a node (called a *label* in the TikZ manual) and the name of a node. The latter is what you use as a coordinate when drawing lines between nodes, but it is completely separate from the text that is shown, so you can have nodes with the same label/text, but different names. This is also demonstrated in  answers below.

Comment: @jlv Thank you for the manual. I had tried with basics but had problem when I was giving same label to vertices. So, I did not put my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the matrix library of tikz as [jlv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19372/jlv) say it :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={shape=circle, draw=black}, row sep=1cm, column sep=1cm] (m)
  {
    Y & P & P & P \\
    R & B & G & Y \\
    P & Y & R & R \\
  };
  \foreach \n in {1,...,4}
  {
    \draw (m-1-\n) -- (m-2-\n);    
    \draw (m-2-\n) -- (m-3-\n);
  }
  \foreach \y/\z in {1/2,2/3,3/4}
  {
    \draw (m-2-\y) -- (m-2-\z);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we draw the edges of second row of m, with for loop?

Comment: see the modifications

Answer (score 1):

more coloreful ...

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary[backgrounds,chains,positioning]

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 12mm and 13mm,
      start chain = going right,
      vrtx/.style = {circle, draw=#1, fill=#1!50, outer sep=0pt,
                     on chain}
                    ]
\foreach \i/\j [count=\k from 1] in {yellow/Y, purple/P, purple/P, purple/P}
    \node (v1\k) [vrtx=\i] {\j};
\foreach \i/\j [count=\k from 1] in {red/R,    blue/B,   green/G, yellow/Y}
    \node (v2\k) [vrtx=\i,below=of v1\k] {\j};
\foreach \i/\j [count=\k from 1] in {purple/P, yellow/Y, red/R,   red/R}
    \node (v3\k) [vrtx=\i,below=of v2\k] {\j};
\scoped[on background layer]
    \draw   (v11) -- (v31)    (v12) -- (v32)
            (v13) -- (v33)    (v14) -- (v34)
            (v21) -- (v24);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]